# 414 URI too long with Apache Tomcat Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, http, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a long uri when i launch my query.
I use `apache tomcat 7.0.42` as server. I know my request is long but i want to increase the uri's length limit to do my requests. Because i always have a

> 414 error : request too long.

How can i do that ?
I've already tried with `maxHttpHeader` in `server.xml` but there was no effects. It appears that : when i restart my server with eclispe, the 'maxHttpHeader' disappears ... why ?

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Is any files to configure or to modify to handle this error ? I really need to.
My request is to fill a dataTable.

Thank's in advanced.

Comment: How did you set the value of `maxHttpHeader` and what value did you set?

Comment: <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just pass my request in POST. Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

> when i restart my server with eclispe, the 'maxHttpHeader' disappears

Using eclipse WTP your tomcat's server config is not (only) stored in the *conf* folder of the tomcat installation.

Go to the *Servers* view and double-click on your server, under *General Information* you will find a *Configuration path* field that points to the configuration directory. Usually this is a folder in a separate eclipse project (called *Servers*).

After editing the `server.xml` there you can synchronize your server (in the *Servers* view) and the changes should not vanish anymore.

**Edit:** As for `maxHttpHeader`: just saw you are defining the `maxHttpHeader` setting for your `8080` connector and using a redirect to `8443`. The setting will not take effect for *https* connections. Try adding the same setting to your `8443`connector.

Comment: ok i did that. Now the parameter stay in the server.xml but i still have the error